# My company HTTP proxy sometimes returns 407 Unauthoriezed and some others it is OK

Tags: http, proxy

I cannot understand how my company proxy actually works.

It sometimes retnurn me a **407 Unauthorized** and sometimes it returns me OK:

```
C:\Users\myuser>curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/randomgit
curl: (56) Received HTTP code 406 from proxy after CONNECT

C:\Users\myuser>curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/randomgit
curl: (56) Received HTTP code 406 from proxy after CONNECT

C:\Users\myuser>curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/randomgit
curl: (56) Received HTTP code 406 from proxy after CONNECT

C:\Users\myuser>curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/randomgit
curl: (56) Received HTTP code 406 from proxy after CONNECT

C:\Users\myuser>curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/randomgit
<html>
   ...
</html>

C:\Users\myuser>curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/randomgit
<html>
   ...
</html>
```

If I use the browser and set the proxy in the Windows settings, I never got the 407 error.

I've set the **ENV varibale HTPPS_PROXY** point to the proxy in order to make the requests from my terminal.

I cannot understand how I am authenticated an why the requests sometimes succeed and sometimes not.

Comment: We don't know how your company proxy works, either. Can you ask your IT support staff?